# JAVA regular expression to replace all occurrences of a particular word "working weird"

Tags: java, regex

Does anyone see something wrong with this regex I have. All I want is for this to find any occurrences of the and replace it with what word the user chooses. This expression only changes some occurrences and when it does it removes the before white space and I guess concatenates it with the word before.
Also it should not replace then, there, their, they etc

```
private final String MY_REGEX = (" the | THE | thE | The | tHe | ThE  ");

        userInput = JTxtInput.getText();
        String usersChoice = JTxtUserChoice.getText();
        String usersChoiceOut = (usersChoice + " ");


        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(MY_REGEX, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(userInput);
        while (matcher.find())
        {
            userInput = userInput.replaceAll(MY_REGEX, usersChoiceOut);
            JTxtOutput.setText(userInput);
            System.out.println(userInput);
        }
```

Ok this new code seems to replace all desired words and nothing else, also doing it without the spacing issues.

```
private final String MY_REGEX = ("the |THE |thE |The |tHe |ThE |THe ");
String usersChoiceOut = (usersChoice + " ");
```

Comment: If you're using CASE_INSENSITIVE you don't need to also spell out all the case variations. Not that you have them all. There are 8, not 6.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is because of the spaces in `MY_REGEX`. Check the following demo:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str="This is the eighth wonder of THE world! How about a new style of writing The as tHe";
        // Correct way
        String MY_REGEX = ("the|THE|thE|The|tHe|ThE");
        System.out.println(str.replaceAll(MY_REGEX, "@@@"));
    }
}
```

**Outputs:**

```
This is @@@ eighth wonder of @@@ world! How about a new style of writing @@@ as @@@
```

**whereas**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str="This is the eighth wonder of THE world! How about a new style of writing The as tHe";
        // Incorrect way
        String MY_REGEX = ("the | THE | thE | The | tHe | ThE");
        System.out.println(str.replaceAll(MY_REGEX, "@@@"));
    }
}
```

**Outputs:**

```
This is @@@eighth wonder of@@@world! How about a new style of writing@@@as tHe
```

Comment: Thanks, that did fix the space issue, I should have known better but I am new to regex.

Answer (score 1):

The spaces in the [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) have meaning and will tried to be matched literally on both sides of the word.

As you are already using `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE`, you could also match *the* followed by a single space as you mention in your updated answer,  and use an inline modifier `(?i)` to make the pattern case insensitive.

```
userInput = userInput.replaceAll("(?i)the ", usersChoiceOut);
```

If *the* should not be part of a larger word, you add a word boundary `\b` before it.

`(?i)\bthe`

Comment: Since you mentioned the word boundary, it can also be used after `the`

Comment: @Clashsoft The word boundary will be present between the `e` char and a space. Adding it will be superfluous in this case.